# How to use java guice when an injectable has its own dependencies

Tags: java, guice

I'm trying to figure out how Guice works and is struggling to find examples/tutorials for the specific scenarios I have.

Lets say I have the following classes:

- **ClassA** with injected **ClassB**
- **ClassB**
- **ClassC** with injected **ClassA**

The problem I'm having is that ClassA does not have a no-arg constructor and also have its own dependencies. I'm not sure how to inject these type of dependencies using an Injector.

ClassA

```
public class ClassA {

    private final int number;
    private final ClassB classB;

    @Inject
    public ClassA(int number, ClassB classB) {
        this.number = number;
        this.classB = classB;
    }

    public String message() {
        return "ClassA number: " + number + ", ClassB number: " + classB.getNumber();
    }

}
```

ClassB

```
@Getter
public class ClassB {

    private final int number;

    @Inject
    public ClassB(@Assisted int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}
```

ClassC

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted;

public class ClassC {

    final private int number;
    final private ClassA classA;

    @Inject
    public ClassC(@Assisted int number, ClassA classA) {
        this.number = number;
        this.classA = classA;
    }

    public String message() {
        String message = classA.messsage();
        return message + ", ClassC number: " + number;
    }

}
```

I have a factory interfaces for all classes with a `create(int number)` method. In the module configure method I have the following:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(ClassAFactory.class));
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(ClassBFactory.class));
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(ClassCFactory.class));
```

The following is where I'm totally lost, how do I mix this all together?

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppModule());

ClassBFactory bFactory = injector.getInstance(ClassBFactory.class);
ClassB b = bFactory.create(2);
ClassAFactory aFactory = injector.getInstance(ClassAFactory.class);
ClassA a = aFactory.create(1);
ClassCFactory cFactory = injector.getInstance(ClassCFactory.class);
ClassC c = cFactory.create(3);

System.out.println(c.message());
```

Output for above:

```
ClassA number: 3, ClassB number: 3, ClassC number: 3
```

Bonus for me, if its possible to use providers instead of factories for this scenario please can someone show me an example of how to resolve these dependencies in a provider?

Comment: This is working as expected. Each of those instances is their own thing. If you want to provide separate values, make sure each `@Assisted` value has a different name. There is no reason to assume the `ClassB` from your `bFactory.getInstance` call will be reused as the dependency of the `aFactory.getInstance` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a feature, believe it or not. It's creating corresponding instances with the same value.

```
ClassBFactory bFactory = injector.getInstance(ClassBFactory.class);
ClassB b = bFactory.create(2);
```

This creates a new `ClassB` instance with `number` of `2`.

```
ClassAFactory aFactory = injector.getInstance(ClassAFactory.class);
ClassA a = aFactory.create(1);
```

The constructor for `ClassA` takes `number` and an instance of `ClassB`. However, the instance of `ClassB` you've created above *is not bound* and isn't available to the Injector. Since `ClassB` can be created using assisted injection, though, it's able to creates one. It does and injects that into the instance of `ClassA`. In this case, both `ClassA` and `ClassB` instances have `number` of `1`.

```
ClassCFactory cFactory = injector.getInstance(ClassCFactory.class);
ClassC c = cFactory.create(3);
```

As above, this creates new `ClassB` and `ClassA` instances for this new `ClassC`, each with `number` of `3`.

If you want to address this, you need to change your factories to take the right dependencies and make those dependencies `@Assisted`.

```
ClassBFactory bFactory = injector.getInstance(ClassBFactory.class);
ClassB b = bFactory.create(2);
ClassAFactory aFactory = injector.getInstance(ClassAFactory.class);
ClassA a = aFactory.create(1, b); // <--
ClassCFactory cFactory = injector.getInstance(ClassCFactory.class);
ClassC c = cFactory.create(3, a); // <--
```

If you're only going to have one instance of each of these classes, this is better done in a `Module` as `@Provides` methods rather than using assisted injection and factories:

```
@Provides
ClassA provideClassA(ClassB b) {
  return new ClassA(1, b);
}

@Provides
ClassB provideClassB() {
  return new ClassB(2);
}

@Provides
ClassC provideClassC(ClassA a) {
  return new ClassC(3, a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this so well. I was very confused by this. The providers using the @Provides annotation works well for me thank you.